# MainPage.xaml takes long to load

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

**What i've done**

```
        BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
        bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
        bg.RunWorkerCompleted += newRunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bg_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bg.RunWorkerAsync(); 

       void DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
       {
       Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate { InitializeComponent(); });
       }
```

The problem is that it is slightly better but there is a obvious load between page animation and when page loads.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here also you have no animation shown, so what exactly is being animated and how? Also the page load method is not shown either? What does the Backgroundworker function as, the window starter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InitializeComponent() is what parses the XAML and loads the visual tree. Delaying it until a background worker completes is an *incredibly* bad idea. You should call InitializeComponent immediately, and display an empty UI or loading progress bar while the background work completes. Do you know about the async/await pattern?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. i think this is a better approach.